# Nav-toggler button position on mobile and tablet resolution

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, hamburger-menu

I have been struggling with this one for days now, any help to sort this out would be greatly appreciated. I need the hamburger icon on the right side, contact picture with phone number on it in the middle ad brand logo on the left. For some reason toggler is getting pushed outside its col-3 grid. I am using bootstrap 4.

```
 <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5 col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <img class="logo img-fluid" src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="tel-icon">
                        <img class="contact img-fluid" src="/img/contact.png" alt="contact-icon">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-none">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                                aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>    
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link home" href="#">HOME</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link security-services" href="#">SECURITY SERVICES</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link contact-us" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>




/////////collapsed nav//////////
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .fa-bars {
        transform: scale(2.2, 1.3);
        -webkit-transform: scale(2.2, 1.3); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: scale(2.2, 1.3); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: scale(2.2, 1.3); /* IE 9+ */
        -o-transform: scale(2.2, 1.3); /* Opera */
        color: white;
        margin: 15px -30px 10px 20px;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        background-color: white;
        margin: 5px 50px 30px 0px;
    }
    .navbar-nav a {
        color: #6d3093;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .fa-bars {
        transform: scale(2.0, 1.2);
        -webkit-transform: scale(2.0, 1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: scale(2.0, 1.2); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: scale(2.0, 1.2); /* IE 9+ */
        -o-transform: scale(2.0, 1.2); /* Opera */
        margin: 15px -30px 10px 20px;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        color: white;
        margin-right: 90px;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        background-color: white;
        margin-top: 18px;
    }

    .navbar-nav a {
        color: #6d3093;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot of your problem?

Comment: It would be better if you recreate the problem in codepen or jsfiddle, also can you explain it a bit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this that you were looking for [codepen](https://codepen.io/YorkFord/pen/dQjyxL)

```
           <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="tel-icon">
                    <img class="contact img-fluid" src="/img/contact.png" alt="contact-icon">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
```

Comment: Not really, toggler is still all over the place when you click on it to collapse the navbar and it's also not in the right side corner as I want it to.

Comment: Hey, I edited my answer, check now, if this isn't what you are looking for can you post an image of how it should look?

Comment: This is how its suppossed to look like on mobile: https://imgur.com/xkZ835u    https://imgur.com/yRnwy1D

Comment: Hey Zokes, check the codepen link again, I edited it, see if this is what you need.

Comment: Thx this helped a lot, still needs some tweakin in css on my part but it works fine now.

Comment: No problem, Glad to help. You can check this answer for accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)